# Option to click on the Add Comment link without a mouse

Tags: feature-request, comments, accessibility, keyboard

My mouse died today.

When I wanted to add a comment with just the keyboard, I found that it was just not possible.

Please add a way for me to be able to add comments without having to make use of the mouse.

Comment: This comment is made possible by the use of arrow keys and Shift on **Opera.** This pointless edit is also possible by the same means.

Comment: Besides "add comment", "flag" is also not-clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has [MouseKeys](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/mousekeys.aspx) and I'm assuming OSX and Linux have something similar, so it is possible given the right configuration of your system.

I would imagine that the kind of user who never used a mouse - rather than just on the odd days it was broken - would be familiar with such tools.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't noticed the missing tab behaviour; but this works with gleeBox on chrome (yes I know the question was opera):

- press g (bring up gleeBox)
- type "add c"
- press enter

Note that since "add c" is in the title, you'd have to press [tab] to get to the right link.

But gleeBox is great; I have it set to apply a jQuery selector by default (`h3>a`) on stackoverflow, so I can [tab] through the titles ;-p